# Shadow Copy Runs, files cannot be backed up

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, vss

I am using Ahsay as our backup system, I am backing up a system that always has files open, typically running a Shadow copy allows the backup to run with no problems on the open files, however on a few systems I am receiving errors that the files cannot be backed up because it is in use or locked.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems? What did you do to resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the service seems to resolve the issue on some of the systems I have experienced this problem on. Sometimes I was only able to resolve the issue by rebuilding the reg key. These have both resolved all of the issues I have seen, so far.